# How to slow down a data stream in c#?

Tags: c#

I have data streaming into a C# application from multiple sources. One has a higher latency than the other, and I need to slow/offset the faster stream to match the slower one.

Each stream is:

The data comes in (three doubles) and is pushed into an array.

`double[] result = new double[3];`

The result is processed, the array is refilled, over and over.

I need a function before the processing, that will slow this process by an adjustable amount. I don't want to use `Sleep` or `Delay` as then i will lose data. Is there a smart way to do this that i am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe synchronize the two streams to that both must provide a value before the next value is requested?

Comment: You have no choice but to lose data unless you're willing to pay for an infinite amount of buffer storage for your faster stream).

Comment: That is what i suspected. I was hoping I had missed something!

Comment: Having said that, would you recommend `Thread.Sleep`, `Task.Delay`, or a different method to offset?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the situation?

Comment: TPL Data flows have a BufferBlock that has throttling capability. Maybe you can use it.